# How do I write a query to count records with multiple constraints and matches?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 5 tables:

1. Files
2. Tags
3. join_File_Tags
4. Profiles
5. join_Profile_Tags

The Profiles and the join_Profile_Tags tables determine which Files a user can see.

Data might look like this:

- **File1** has tags **One**, **Three**
- **File2** has tags **One**, **Five**
- **File3** has tags **One**, **Three**, **Six**
- **Profile1** has access to tags **Two**, **Three**, **Four**
- **Profile2** has access to tags **One**, **Two**, **Three**, **Four**, **Five**

I needed a query that returns the files that match ALL of its tags inside a Profile's list of tags.

And I came up with this:

```
SELECT 
    files.id,
    files.FileName,
    (SELECT COUNT(j_file_tags.id) from j_file_tags  WHERE j_file_tags.fileID = files.id ) as fileTagCount
FROM files
LEFT JOIN j_file_tags ON j_file_tags.fileID = files.id
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = j_file_tags.tagID
WHERE
    files.caseID = '123456'
    AND 
    j_file_tags.tagID IN ("One, Two, Three, Four, Five") /* i can get these before hand */
GROUP BY 
    files.id
HAVING 
    COUNT(j_file_tags.id) = fileTagCount /* this makes sure that the user has access to ALL the tags applied to the file*/
```

This gives me exactly what I need. BUT what I'm trying to get now is: how many files are there in each tag?

So in my example data at the top, the **Profile2** user will see **File1** and **File2** but not **File3** because that one has tag **six**, which profile2 doesn't have access to. I need a query that builds a tag cloud (no biggie based on the j_profile_tags table) but I need the tags to include file count. I need tag **One** to show the number 2, **Three** shows 1, **Five** shows 1. The queries I attempted so far include the count for all the files, so tag **One** comes in with a count of 3 even though **Profile2** doesn't have access to that third file. 
Here's my half working query:

```
SELECT
    tags.id,
    tags.TagName,
    COUNT(tags.id) as tagCount
FROM
    tags
INNER JOIN j_file_tags ON tags.id = j_file_tags.tagID
INNER JOIN files ON j_file_tags.fileID = files.id
INNER JOIN j_profile_tags ON j_profile_tags.tagID = tags.id AND j_profile_tags.profileID = 'Profile2'
WHERE
    files.caseID = '123456'
GROUP BY
    tags.id
```

Comment: When LEFT JOIN, put the right side table's conditions in the ON clause to get true left join behavior. (When in WHERE, you get inner join result...)

Comment: I updated the INNER JOIN in my last query as you suggested.

Comment: I comment was rather regarding your first query, the one with LEFT JOIN's.

Answer (score 0):

I dont fully understand about your tables, especially that ***"Employee"*** Column.
But if what you mean is getting ***How many Files that contained in each Tag filtered by a Profile***, then please try below queries:

```
DECLARE @TblFiles AS TABLE(ID int identity(1, 1) primary key, TheFileName varchar(50))
DECLARE @TblTags AS TABLE(ID int identity(1, 1) primary key, TheTag varchar(50))
DECLARE @TblProfiles AS TABLE(ID int identity(1, 1) primary key, TheProfile varchar(50))

DECLARE @TblFileTagMapper AS TABLE(ID int identity(1, 1) primary key, FileID int, TagID int)
DECLARE @TblProfileTagMapper AS TABLE(ID int identity(1, 1) primary key, ProfileID int, TagID int)

INSERT INTO @TblFiles(TheFileName) VALUES ('File1'), ('File2'), ('File3')
INSERT INTO @TblTags(TheTag) VALUES ('One'), ('Two'), ('Three'), ('Four'), ('Five'), ('Six')
INSERT INTO @TblProfiles(TheProfile) VALUES ('Profile1'), ('Profile2')
INSERT INTO @TblFileTagMapper(FileID, TagID) VALUES (1,1), (1,3), (2,1), (2,5), (3,1), (3,3), (3,6)
INSERT INTO @TblProfileTagMapper(ProfileID, TagID) VALUES (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5)

--Display File-Tag
SELECT  TheFileName
       ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(TheTag AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM (SELECT F.TheFileName, T.TheTag FROM @TblFileTagMapper FT INNER JOIN @TblFiles F ON FT.FileID = F.ID INNER JOIN @TblTags T ON FT.TagID = T.ID) FT 
         WHERE TheFileName = t.TheFileName
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') Tags
FROM (SELECT F.TheFileName, T.TheTag FROM @TblFileTagMapper FT INNER JOIN @TblFiles F ON FT.FileID = F.ID INNER JOIN @TblTags T ON FT.TagID = T.ID) t
GROUP BY TheFileName

--Display Profile-Tag
SELECT  TheProfile
       ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(TheTag AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM (SELECT P.TheProfile, T.TheTag FROM @TblProfileTagMapper PT INNER JOIN @TblProfiles P ON PT.ProfileID = P.ID INNER JOIN @TblTags T ON PT.TagID = T.ID) PT
         WHERE TheProfile = t.TheProfile
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') Tags
FROM (SELECT P.TheProfile, T.TheTag FROM @TblProfileTagMapper PT INNER JOIN @TblProfiles P ON PT.ProfileID = P.ID INNER JOIN @TblTags T ON PT.TagID = T.ID) t
GROUP BY TheProfile

--> Param Input
DECLARE @ParamProfile VARCHAR(50) = 'Profile2'

--> The Solution Query
SELECT T.TheTag, COALESCE(X.FileCount, 0) AS NumberOfFilesWhichContainTheTag
FROM @TblTags T
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT FT.TagID, COUNT(FT.FileID) AS FileCount
    FROM @TblFileTagMapper FT
    WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @TblProfileTagMapper PT INNER JOIN @TblProfiles P ON PT.ProfileID = P.ID WHERE PT.TagID = FT.TagID AND P.TheProfile = @ParamProfile)
    GROUP BY FT.TagID

) X ON T.ID = X.TagID
```

*These might be not the real answer to your question, but might be a help to get you there.*

Comment: your last query returns the ist of tags the profile has access to along with the number of files that have that tag BUT:  (1) it also returns all the other tags with a 0 count for files, those rows would not be needed AND most importantly (2) the count is for all the files in the file table, how would I add one more condition there? like that "where files.caseID = 1